# tkinter not firing second GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is my first time experimenting with both GUIs and python so any guidance would be appreciated.  I wrote a tkinter GUI contained in client.py that I would like to have displayed first.  Upon successful login, a second gui should appear which is contained in menu.py.  I cannot understand why menu.py's gui isn't appearing properly after I login.  I have tried taking all of the contents from Menu.py and placing them in Client.py, but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

What happens is: 
1.) login GUI appears
2.) I login w/ correct credentials
3.) I get 200 OK message
4.) An empty GUI appears and I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pat\Documents\GitHub\DunderMifflinSales\DunderMifflinClient.py", line 51, in _login_btn_clicked
    mf = Menu.MenuFrame(menu)
  File "C:\Users\Pat\Documents\GitHub\DunderMifflinSales\Menu.py", line 9, in __init__
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

What is intended to happen is as follows:
1.) login GUI appears
2.) login w/ correct credentials
3.) menu gui appears

I am having a hard time understanding why my logic isn't working. Thanks for any help I receive.

Client.py

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
from tkinter import ttk
import Menu

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


class LoginFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()


    def _login_btn_clicked(self):

        username = self.entry_1.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(username.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        password = self.entry_2.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(password.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        message, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        message = message.decode('UTF-8')

        if message == "200 OK":
            tm.showinfo("Logged in", message)
            menu = Tk()
            menu.title("Dunder Mifflin GUI")
            mf = Menu.MenuFrame(menu)
            menu.mainloop()

        else:
            tm.showinfo("Login error", message)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Dunder Mifflin GUI")
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(270, 80))
    lf = LoginFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Menu.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MenuFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
        mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        name = "John"
        sales = StringVar()
        moreSales = StringVar()
        sales.set("1")

        welcome = "Welcome, " + name + "!"

        sales_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = moreSales)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = welcome).grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = W)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Current Sales:").grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = sales).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (E))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "sales").grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = W)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Add Sales").grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = W)
        sales_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Add", command = MenuFrame.add(sales, moreSales)).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)

        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Log Out", command = MenuFrame.logout).grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = W)

    def add(sales, moreSales):

        try:
            value1 = int(sales.get())
            value2 = int(moreSales.get())
            sales.set(value1 + value2)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def logout():
        root.destroy()
```

Comment: You've completely changed the nature of your question with your most recent edit. Why don't you spend a bit more time debugging before asking a question. The time I spent answering your original question was completely wasted.

Comment: Your comment was extremely useful even though I did alter the nature of the question.  I apologize for 'wasting' your time although I would argue that your time wasn't wasted because you gave me a fuller understanding of what's occurring.  Thank you for your time and I apologize.

Comment: Python is telling you exactly what's wrong. `root` is not defined. How can there be a problem here?

Comment: I thought `root` is defined at the bottom of Menu.py.  When I move it from the bottom of Menu.py to before `mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")`, the gui fires properly but an extra empty gui is fired.

Comment: You are creating two main windows (Tk()) but Tkinter doesn't support that. Use a toplevel window for one of the windows.